# How can I catch invalid user input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It checks if the number is bigger or smaller or not and also if the user has quit by entering `"q"`. But it doesn't catch invalid input like `"&, *, (, p, ]"`  with `"while(!guess)"`.

```js
let guess = window.prompt('guess the number!');
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let tries = 0;
while (!guess) {
  let guess = parseInt(prompt('enter a valid number'));
}

while (parseInt(guess) !== rand) {
  tries += 1;
  if (guess === 'q') {
    console.log('you have exited');
    break;
  }
  if (guess < rand) guess = prompt('enter higher!');
  else guess > rand;
  guess = prompt('enter lower!');
}

console.log(`correct number is : ${rand} and it took you ${tries} tries`);
```

Comment: Probably because you're not converting the initial guess to an integer. A value of "&" is a non-empty string and is therefore truthy, which means the first while loop would be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the value of `guess` to see if it matches any of the special characters using Regex with [String.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

```js
while (!guess || /[&*()\[\]p]/g.test(guess)) {
  let guess = prompt('enter a valid number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use else if between each conditional.  Your final else would be something like, 'Invalid key pressed. Try again.'

```
if (guess === 'q') {...} else
if (parseInt(guess) < rand) {...} else
if (parseInt(guess) > rand {...}
else guess = prompt('Invalid key entered. Please try again.');
```